# Change the size of blocks

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-resource-packs, minecraft-addons

How do I change the size of a block, making it take up more or less pixels, therefore making it apear appear large or small using addons?

Comment: i believe it is not possible to actually change block size in bedrock edition, it is possible with mods in java. however, you can use invisible armor stands and player heads that look like blocks to achieve a similar effect using commands

Comment: @Topcode I have seen it before.

Comment: You can using block models

Comment: @Penguin What are those? Answer this question

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=minecraft+bedrock+edition+block+models I wont answer because I dont know how to do it myself, heres a pointer